# How to send data from C++ desktop App to Google Firebase?

Tags: android, c++, firebase, image-uploading

I'm developing a C++ App that performs image processing on images captured by labtop Cam. Once I got the image i need to upload it automatically to my Firebase database to be available for an Android App attached to my system.

How can i pass these images to Firebase. Even though, I know there is no SDK for desktop Apps to the Firebase. Is there any intermediary solutions can handle this Auto-uploading process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that you can run scripts with C++ using `system` (you can find more [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/))

So write code that uploads the image with python or nodejs (choose your preferred language that has firebase SDK), And you can execute it anytime with your C++ program.

Comment: Brilliant idea! 
The following link discusses your point from a more practical perspective.
 https://nodeaddons.com/getting-your-c-to-the-web-with-node-js/
Thanks!